# Disable click on last column in each row

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap table. currently when you click on columns you get an alert. What I want is when you click on last column nothing will happen. Will appreciate your help.

```js
$('#students tbody').on('click', 'tr.details-control', function() {
   alert('click');
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="students" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>....</th>
  <th>Last</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="details-control">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>......</td>
    <td>No Alert</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="details-control">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>......</td>
    <td>No Alert</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('#students tbody').on('click', 'tr.details-control:not(:last)', function() {
 alert('click');
 });`

Comment: When I click on first row I am getting alert, on second not..

Comment: So what you want?

Comment: I dont want alert in all last columns in each row.

Comment: You don't need to append _solved_ to the title. By accepting an answer others will see that the question is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `:not()` with `:last-child` selectors like below:-

```
$('#students tbody').on('click', 'tr.details-control td:not(:last-child)', function() {
  alert('click');
});
```

Working example:-

```js
$('#students tbody').on('click', 'tr.details-control td:not(:last-child)', function() {
  alert('click');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="students" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>....</th>
  <th>Last</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="details-control">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>......</td>
    <td>No Alert</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="details-control">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>......</td>
    <td>No Alert</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Eventually I was targeting only `tr`, hence the issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
$('td:last-child').click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the event to the `td` element like that:

```
$('#students tbody').on('click', 'tr.details-control td:not(:last)', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 $('table').on('click','td:not(:last-child)',function(){
 alert('hi')
 })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>

<table  class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>....</th>
  <th>Last</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="details-control">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>......</td>
    <td>No Alert</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="details-control">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>......</td>
    <td>No Alert</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A short explanation of how you have corrected the answer would be more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('#students tr.details-control').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).context.rowIndex == $('#students tr').length -1){
        e.preventDefault();
    }else
        alert('click');
 });
```